# Difficulty connecting to REDCap api in Julia

Tags: api, julia, redcap

I am trying to use Julia to connect to the REDCap API.
I would like to export a report from a REDCap project as a database.
I keep getting a MethodError that I cannot understand

Here is the code: (I have de-identified the code, however the URL, API_KEY and report_ID are exactly identical to the values I use in the R [redcapAPI](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=redcapAPI) which works seamlessly)

```
using REDCap

REDCAP_API = "string of values"
REDCAP_URL = "url"

config_key = REDCap.Config(REDCAP_URL, REDCAP_API, ssl = true)

export_report(config = config_key, report_id = 1000)
```

I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> MethodError: no method matching export_report(; 
> config=REDCap.Config("url", "string of values", true), report_id=1000)
> Closest candidates are:
>   export_report(!Matched::REDCap.Config, !Matched::Any; format, 
> returnFormat, rawOrLabel, rawOrLabelHeaders, exportCheckboxLabel, 
> file_loc) at 
> C:\Users\username\.julia\packages\REDCap\1M6Y9\src\Export.jl:348 got 
> unsupported keyword arguments "config", "report_id"
> top-level scope at none:0
> ```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`config` and `report_id` are positional rather than named parameters in `REDcap.jl`. You just need to change it to something like:

```
export_report(config_key, 1000)
```